Zabbix nodeAddress hardcode
First look to powerful tool - Zabbix. Setup it with helm and after check up some widgets, see a error block, telling about incorrectness of NodeAddress, simply giving me some hardcode IP instead of actual. Trying resolving this issue - scroll up/down all manifest in entire chart, find only env-variable declaration
- name: ZBX_NODEADDRESS
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: status.podIP

Obviously it responsible for invalid hardcode value.
deployment-zabbix-server.yaml
Is this a bug or feature?)
